# Ruby cgi table error

Tags: html, ruby, cgi

I am writing the cgi ruby and received the following error:

```
ruby5_ac1.cgi:74: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC
```

I think there is the error with the curly at the end of `cgi.table`, but all the curly is match so **I don't know what's wrong with this**.

Code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'
cgi = CGI.new("html4")
cgi.out {
cgi.html {
  cgi.head { cgi.title{"Search Job Bank"} } + "\n" + 
  cgi.body { "\n" + 
      cgi.h1 { "Jobs from VA databank" } +
      cgi.table("border"=>"1")
  {
      cgi.tr {
     cgi.td {"Artist"} + 
     cgi.td {"Album"} } +
      cgi.tr {
     cgi.td {"Davis, Miles"} +
         cgi.td {"Kind of Blue"} } 
      }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as below :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'
cgi = CGI.new("html4")
cgi.out {
cgi.html {
  cgi.head { cgi.title{"Search Job Bank"} } + "\n" + 
  cgi.body { "\n" + 
      cgi.h1 { "Jobs from VA databank" } +
      cgi.table("border"=>"1") { # <~~ see this is a fix.
      # you placed this `{` below of `cgi.table("border"=>"1")` 
      # so it seemed like a Hash. But it should be a block's open brace.
      cgi.tr {
     cgi.td {"Artist"} + 
     cgi.td {"Album"} } +
      cgi.tr {
     cgi.td {"Davis, Miles"} +
         cgi.td {"Kind of Blue"} } 
      }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks a lot, I spent too much on this one